# Building a string Concat array with the same ID inside a query loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, concatenation

i have a query inside a for loop that getting the product name of every array element. Now in every element of my array, i have an ID, where i want to concat all product names with the-same shipping_id.

Here i have my array with values like these:

Array name:`id`  with values of:

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1
            [shipping_id] => 1
        )
   [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 2
            [shipping_id] => 1
        )

   [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1
            [shipping_id] => 2
        )
)
```

now i made this code with these:

```
   $first = true;
    $temp_ship_id = "";
    $product_list = "";
    foreach ($ids as $product) { 
        $productname = $this->getproductname($product[0][product_id]);
        // if($first) {
        //     $temp_ship_id = $product[0][shipping_id];                    
        //     $first = false;
        // }
        // if($product[0][shipping_id] == $temp_ship_id) {
        //     $product_list .= $productname.";
        // } else {
        //     $product_list .= $productname.";
        //     //$product_list = "";                    
        //     $temp_ship_id = $product[0]->shipping_id;
        // }
    }

    public function getproductname($product_id) {
            $product = DB::table('products')->select('product_name')
                ->where(['products.product_id'=>$product_id])
                ->first();


            return $product->product_name;    
    }
```

what am i doing is, i am getting the first shipping id and store it and i made a condition if they are thesame then i go concat the productname but, i see my logic is bad.

Please help me in other way. Something like This line of code to begin with:

```
foreach ($ids as $product) { 
    $productname = $this->getproductname($product[0][product_id]);
    //code for concat goes here
}

public function getproductname($product_id) {
        $product = DB::table('products')->select('product_name')
            ->where(['products.product_id'=>$product_id])
            ->first();


        return $product->product_name;    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust below to your actual data, let me know if you have questions.

```
<?php
    $concat = array();
    $array  = array( array( 'product_id'=>1, 'shipping_id'=>1, 'product_name' => 'a' ), array( 'product_id'=>2, 'shipping_id'=>1, 'product_name' => 'b' ), array( 'product_id'=>3, 'shipping_id'=>2, 'product_name' => 'c' ), array( 'product_id'=>4, 'shipping_id'=>1, 'product_name' => 'd' ) );
    foreach( $array as $row ) {
        if( isset( $concat[ $row['shipping_id'] ] ) ) {
            $concat[ $row['shipping_id'] ] .= ',' . $row['product_name'];
        } else {
            $concat[ $row['shipping_id'] ] .= $row['product_name'];
        }
    }
    var_dump( $concat );
?>
```

Comment: thanks i'll adjust this, i will have questions later .. thank you

Comment: your answer is correct. please help me. i have an error in applying to mine. maybe i got wrong logically. i got error undefined offset: 7
foreach ($ids as $updateprod) { 
        $productname = $this->updateProductQty($updateprod[0]->product_id,$updateprod[0]->quantity);
                if( isset( $concat[ $updateprod[0]->shipping_id ] ) ) {
                    $concat[ $updateprod[0]->shipping_id ] .= ',' . $productname;
                } else {
                    $concat[ $updateprod[0]->shipping_id ] .= $productname;
                }
            }
            print_r($concat);

Comment: you have `$concat[ $updateprod[0]->shipping_id ] .= $productname;` in your `else` statement, where it should be `$concat[ $updateprod[0]->shipping_id ] = $productname;` you have an extra `.`

Comment: hello sir, how can i add mobile_number elements per array? something like, i'll add in $concat[ $updateprod[0]->shipping_id ] i will add mobile_number element